# What is a void in CAD

Tags: autocad, cad, geometry

I'm using existing architectural designs and some mechanical designs too, all CAD files in formats *.dwg, *.dgn and the drawings have smart solid geometries including voids. Using CAD software what is a void space and why is it important to create voids as an object?

Comment: In an architectural drawing, a void is often a "thing", in the sense that bricklayers think in terms like "I need to build a brick wall here, but leave a hole in it for a door or a window", not "I need to build some arbitrary-shaped structure out of bricks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a void geometry in a window object in order to make a hole when you insert the window in a wall. Autodesk Revit works like this.